# -fno-objc-arc automatically add compiler flag to many files that use retain and release messages

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I just re added all my files to the project and there are about 150 files that need to use -fno-objc-arc because of release. Is there any quick way to add -fno-objc-arc flag to all files that use arc without adding this flag manually to all 150 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. On the Build Phases tab of your target, select all 150 files in the Compile Sources section. Then double-click in the Compiler Flags column of one of the selected files. Enter `-fno-objc-arc` into the little popup window then press Enter.

The flag will be added to all of the selected files.

A better solution would be to refactor the old MRC code into ARC code. Simply delete all calls to `release`, `retain`, and `autorelease`. Remove the call to `[super dealloc]` in your `dealloc` method. If `dealloc` is now empty, remove the whole method.

Comment: thank for answer. ok that perfect solution if all my files will not support ARC, but if I selected all files some of then can be ARC compatible and in this case it will cause leaks. So it means I should select all files manually in build phase using 'Shift', but in this case I should check 150 files form 300 files of my project. It means I need to make 150 clicks. Especially if I use 3rd libraries, I will not see which classes use ARC and which not.

Comment: Using Cmd-click will let you select specific multiple files. You have to know which ones require the flag. There's no automated way. It would be much easier to tell Xcode to convert the project to ARC. It will remove all of the `release` and other non-ARC calls from the files.